# RecyclerView is not Iterating the layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating a RecyclerView for my android application with some dummy data which has two set of datas. But the layout is not iterating twice instead it shows the first data correctly.

```
public class HomeScreenFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<String> flags = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> leagues = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();

    private Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        initData();

    }

    private void initData() {
        leagues.add("Indian premiere league");
        dates.add("03-Dec");

        leagues.add("Srilankan Premiere league");
        dates.add("04-Dec");

        initRecyclerView();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.homeRecyclerView);
        HomeScreenRVAdapter adapter = new HomeScreenRVAdapter(flags,leagues,dates,context);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    }
}
```

RecyclerView

```
public class HomeScreenRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeScreenRVAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "HomeScreenRVAdapter";

    private String BASE_URL, API_KEY;

    private ArrayList<String> flags = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> leagues = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    public HomeScreenRVAdapter(ArrayList<String> flags, ArrayList<String> leagues, ArrayList<String> dates, Context context) {
        this.flags = flags;
        this.leagues = leagues;
        this.dates = dates;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_home, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.league.setText(leagues.get(position));
        holder.date.setText(dates.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return leagues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        // HEADER WIDGETS
        ExpansionHeader expansionHeader;
        ImageView flag;
        TextView league, date;

        // LAYOUT WIDGETS
        ExpansionLayout expansionLayout;
        TextView minutes, local, visitor, localScore, visitorScore;
        ImageView favourite;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            expansionHeader = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expansionHeader);
            flag = itemView.findViewById(R.id.headerFlag);
            league = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expansionHeaderLeague);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expansionHeaderDate);

        }
    }
}
```

I want to make the app iterate the layout (layout_home) as many times as data comes. But it is not iterating. Otherwise is there anyway to iterate only the expansion layout alone?

Comment: your recyclerView and your adapter are not properly implemented. And you don't need to separate your flag, league, and date into 3 ArrayList.  You can do these only into one ArrayList.

Comment: @Mak-MakBasaya Would you be able to expand on the implementation issues? If it's just the three different arrays, then I do not think that would cause such an error.

Comment: The problem here is the layout is not iterating

Comment: @deluxan It would be helpful if you posted your layout file too (layout_home)

Comment: It is working after changing from `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in layout_home.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. There is most probably an issue in `layout_home`. Make sure `android:layout_height` is set to `wrap_content`.

Moreover, you could implement a custom object `ArrayList` instead of creating three separate ones. The custom object would hold the properties of each item. However, this is a suggestion and I do not think this is the cause of the bug you are facing.

Comment: You are a genius. That was the issue. It's working fine now

Comment: Aah thanks! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is the correct answers but Another approach and good coding practices I made it for you.

First, we need to initialize the RecyclerView

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.homeRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        HomeScreenRVAdapter adapter = new HomeScreenRVAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Then create the recyclerView Adapter called **HomeScreenRVAdapter.java**

```
public class HomeScreenRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeScreenRVAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<League> leagues = new ArrayList<>();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_home, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        League league = leagues.get(position);
        holder.league.setText(league.getLeague());
        holder.date.setText(league.getDate());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return leagues.size();
    }

    void setList(List<League> list) {
        this.leagues = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView flag;
        TextView league, date;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            flag = itemView.findViewById(R.id.headerFlag);
            league = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expansionHeaderLeague);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expansionHeaderDate);
        }
    }
}
```

create getter and setter class called **League.java**

```
class League {
    private String flag;
    private String league;
    private String date;

    public League(String flag, String league, String date) {
        this.flag = flag;
        this.league = league;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public String getLeague() {
        return league;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

then in your onViewCreated() add your data like this.

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        List<League> leagues = new ArrayList<>();
        leagues.add(new League("Flag1","Indian premiere league","03-Dec"));
        leagues.add(new League("Flag2","Srilankan Premiere league","04-Dec"));

        adapter.setList(leagues);
    }
```

> notifyDataSetChanged();

is very important. don't forget to add after data changed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll try with it. Assume If I am getting a string from api and I stored it in a variable and I am doing the following coding but it showing empty. Anyhow the string is showing data in Log. `new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
try {
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
Log.d("League ID", league_id);
leagues.add(league_id); // This thing is not working}`